# Compute the first 10 Fibonacci numbers

Tags: matlab, fibonacci

I need to write a code in matlab that compute 
[the first 10 Fibonacci numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFOqx.png)
But I am having some trouble with this. I thought of using the formula defined here:

https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10002.4-5.shtml

And I've gotten this so far

```
n = 0; 
c = (((1+sqrt(5))/2)^n -((1-sqrt(5))/2)^2)/(sqrt(5));
while (n < 10)
disp(c)
n+1;
end
```

But as you can probably see, it is very wrong and incomplete. But I'm not sure what to do else. The professor wants us to write a proper code, meaning I can't use things like fibonacci(n). Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fib_series = [0,1];
i = 3;
while length(fib_series) < 10
  fib_series(i) = fib_series(i-1) + fib(i-2);
  i = i+1;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember what a fibonacci number is defined as:

```
fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
```

Your formula is massively overkill for calculating the first 10. Just set the first 2 as constants and calculate the others (using an array as once you calculate the third you can calculate the 4th) from that using what you know.

i'll leave some pseudocode for a recursion that calculates it, you should be able to translate the idea over to matlab

```
let fib = [0,1,-1,-1...]
function Fibonacci(n){
  if (fib[n] != -1) return fib[n] // If it exists already, we have it!
  // otherwise, we can calculate it
  // make sure to save the result so we can use it later if needed.
  fib[n] = Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2);
  return fib[n];
}
```

Comment: He stated that he doesn't want to use a recursive funtion

Comment: The question doesn't state that, it says you can't just use the built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like fibonaacci series follows the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), as talked about in some detail [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html).

This was used in this [MATLAB File-exchange code](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29991-vectorized-fibonacci/content//fibonacci.m) and I am writing here, just the esssence of it -

```
sqrt5 = sqrt(5);
alpha = (1 + sqrt5)/2;   %// alpha = 1.618... is the golden ratio
fibs  = round( alpha.^n ./ sqrt5 )
```

You can feed an integer into `n` for the `nth` number in `Fibonacci Series` or feed an array `1:n` to have the whole series.

Please note that this method holds good till `n = 69` only.